# Get driver id in Spark Standalone cluster in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

How can i get the driver id of the already submitted/running application, programmatically or if there is any end point which i am missing ? 
I have gone through the Spark hidden REST APIs which gives only three end points: /create /status /kill . Now, to kill the application, i need the driver id/submission id of the application.

EDIT :

[image]

Comment: What exactly is driver ID here? You can kill a application if you have the application ID.

Comment: I added one picture having the driver id and application ID. The end points which i mentioned takes the driver ID not the application ID. Can you please tell me how to kill the application using application ID programmatically ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't access imgur at work. You can kill a Spark app by using `yarn application -kill applicationID`. You can get the ID programmatically using `SparkContext.applicationID`

Comment: I am not using YARN. I am using spark standalone cluster.

Comment: Apologies. I din't read the question correctly. Sorry for irrelevant information.

Comment: Did you find a way to get this driver id?

Comment: @Vince.Bdn The driver id can be fetched using the REST URL and running the job in cluster mode.
For what purpose, do you need the driver id, may be i can hep you with that

Comment: @sunilkumar I want the driver-id exactly for the same purpose you wanted it, to kill application in stadalone. You say it can be fetched using the REST URL and running the job in cluster mode. I assume you mean the [public api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) and not the hidden one. If yes, how? I dont see a way you can reach to driver-Id with these endpoints. And even if you could, After the submission, one of the workers take control of the driver and you don't have any port 4040 on the node that you submitted the app in the first place.

Comment: @sunilkumar the only possible way I see is to extract the driver-Id from the logs. When you submit the job in the submitter node, it sends back a json response containing the driver-Id before it gives the control of the driver to any worker. I wonder how they take care of it in SparkUI.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't notice this before but if you submit through hidden API(6066) then the response will have driver-Id :). Hidden API can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/arturmkrtchyan/5d8559b2911ac951d34a#file-submit_job-sh), and the response example is also provided.